# Table content gets outside of the table?

Tags: php, html-table, echo

I'm trying to echo out a table with information, specifically posts.

```
<?php
echo "
<div class='forum_banner'>
    <div style='float:left;'>
        <a href='?action=forum'>Forum</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=forum#".fetch_info(fetch_info(fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'board_id', 'topic'), 'category_id', 'board'), 'name', 'category')."'>".fetch_info(fetch_info(fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'board_id', 'topic'), 'category_id', 'board'), 'name', 'category')."</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=board&id=".fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'board_id', 'topic')."'>".fetch_info(fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'board_id', 'topic'), 'name', 'board')."</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=topic&id=".$_GET['id']."'>".fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'name', 'topic')."</a>
    </div>";
    if (isset($_SESSION['id']))
    {
        echo "
        <div style='float:right;'>
            <form method='post' action='?action=create&type=reply&id=".$_GET['id']."'>
                <input type='submit' value='Reply'/>
            </form>
        </div>";
    }
    echo "
</div>";


echo "
<div class='content'>
    <table class='forum_table'>";
        $query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM post WHERE topic_id='".$_GET['id']."' ORDER BY time ASC") or die(mysql_error());

        echo "
        <tr>
            <td class='table_header' colspan='2'>
                <b>".fetch_info($_GET['id'], 'name', 'topic')."</b>
            </td>
        </tr>";
        while($query_fetch = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
        {
            echo "
            <tr>
                <td class='forum_table_cell_post' width='25%'>
                    <ul class='post_info'>
                        <li><b><a href='?action=user&id=".$query_fetch['creator']."'>".fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'name', 'user')."</a></b></li>
                        <li>".fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'rank', 'user')."</li>
                        <li style='max-width:128px; max-height:128px; overflow:hidden;'><img src='".fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'avatar', 'user')."' /></li>
                        <li>Posts: ".count_post($query_fetch['creator'])."</li>
                        <li>Reputation: ".(fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'reputation', 'user')>0 ? ('<font color="#007D00">+'.fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'reputation', 'user').'</font>') : (fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'reputation', 'user')<0 ? ('<font color="#7D0000">'.fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'reputation', 'user').'</font>') : ('<font color="#000000">'.fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'reputation', 'user').'</font>')))."</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
                <td class='forum_table_cell_post' width='75%'>
                    <ul class='post_info'>
                        <li><i>".convert_date($query_fetch['time']) + ($query_fetch['edit']=='0000-00-00 00:00:00' ? '' : (', last edit: '.convert_date($query_fetch['edit'])))."</i></li>
                        <div class='spacer'></div>
                        <li>".$query_fetch['body']."</li>
                        ".(fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'signature', 'user') ? '<div class=\'spacer\'></div>' : '')."
                        <li>".fetch_info($query_fetch['creator'], 'signature', 'user')."</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            ";
        }
        echo "
    </table>
</div>";
?>
```

This is what I end up with (HTML output):

```
<div class='forum_banner'>
    <div style='float:left;'>
        <a href='?action=forum'>Forum</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=forum#General'>General</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=board&id=1'>General discussion</a>
        >
        <a href='?action=topic&id=1'>First topic</a>
    </div>
        <div style='float:right;'>
            <form method='post' action='?action=create&type=reply&id=1'>
                <input type='submit' value='Reply'/>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
<div class='content'>
    <table class='forum_table'>
        <tr>
            <td class='table_header' colspan='2'>
                <b>First topic</b>
            </td>
        </tr>0</i></li>
                        <div class='spacer'></div>
                        <li>Nice first post!</li>
                        <div class='spacer'></div>
                        <li>"Non incautus futuri"</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>
            0</i></li>
                        <div class='spacer'></div>
                        <li>This is the first topic ever made! This is the first topic ever made! This is the first topic ever made!</li>
                        <div class='spacer'></div>
                        <li>"Non incautus futuri"</li>
                    </ul>
                </td>
            </tr>

    </table>
</div>
```

The php file is "include'd" in the index.php like this: "include 'topic.php'" and it's ment to echo out a table of data from my database. Why is this happening?
Also, here is my stylesheet:

```
body {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%; background-color:#F0F2F3; font-family: 'Calibri', sans-serif; font-size:16px; background-image:url(img/pattern.png); background-repeat:repeat;}

p {margin:0; padding:0 0 5px 0;}
a:link,a:visited {color:#003399; text-decoration:none;}
a:hover,a:active,a:focus {color:#FF9933;}
input[type='textbox'],input[type='password'] {margin:0; padding:2px; height:16px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000;}
input[type='submit'] {cursor:pointer; margin:0; height: 22px; padding:2px 6px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-color:#FFFFFF; color:#000000;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;}
input[type='submit']:hover,input[type='submit']:focus {background-color:#99CCCC; color:#FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;}
img {margin:0; padding:0; border:none;}

.page_wrapper {margin:0 auto; padding:0; width:900px;}

#header_area {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}
#header_box {margin:0; padding:0; width:900px;}
#header {float:left; margin:30px auto; padding:0;}

#user_panel {float:right; margin:26px auto; height:40px;}

#menu {margin:0; padding:0; list-style-type:none; width:100%; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; border-bottom:none; background-color:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden;}
#menu li {margin:0; padding:0;}
#menu a:link,#menu a:visited {float:left; margin:0; border-right:1px solid #CCCCCC; padding:10px 25px; color:#000000; background-color:#FFFFFF; text-decoration:none; font-weight:bold;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;}
#menu a:hover,#menu a:active,#menu a:focus {background-color:#99CCCC; color:#FFFFFF;
-webkit-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;
-moz-transition: background 0.4s linear, color 0.4s linear;}

#content_area {margin:0; padding:0; width:100%;}
#content_box {margin:0; padding:0; width:900px; border:1px solid #CCCCCC; background-color:#FFFFFF; overflow:hidden;}
#home_sidebar {margin:0; padding:0; width:30%; float:left;}
#home_content {margin:0; padding:0; width:70%; float:right;}
.content {height:2000px; margin:10px; padding:0; overflow:hidden;}

.small_box {margin:0 150px; padding:0; border:1px solid #CCCCCC;}

.forum_table {margin:0; padding:0; border:none; width:100%;}
.forum_table_cell {margin:0; padding:0px 10px; background-color:#F0F2F3; height:60px;}
.forum_table_cell_post {margin:0; padding:10px; background-color:#F0F2F3; vertical-align:text-top;}
.table_header {padding:0 10px; margin:0; height:30px; font-size:18px; background-color:#FF9933;}

.spacer {margin:5px 0; padding:0; border-top:1px solid #CCCCCC;}

.forum_banner {margin: 10px 10px 0 10px; overflow:hidden; height:22px;}

.post_info {list-style-type:none; padding:0; margin:0;}
.post_info li {margin:2px 0 0 0; padding:0; vertical-align:text-top;}
```

Comment: This does not seem to be the html that is generated by the php you posted. There is no `<tbody>` element echoed out in your php for example. You should post the real html source, not what for example firebug or the developer tools are showing you. And what is the problem exactly?

Comment: Woops, I accidently grabbed the HTML from Chrome's "inspect element" thing, I updated the post with the correct code!

Answer (score 1):

The html looks like a mess.

The first things you should do are to make sure you generate valid html:

- don't put in `<div>` elements as direct children of `<ul>`;
- use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php) on all variables you output to html to make sure the values don't break the html.
- use `&gt;` instead of `>`, etc.

Also, your query has an sql injection hole. You should switch to PDO (or mysqli) with prepared statements and bound variables to avoid that or at the very least cast your `$_GET` variable to `int` if it is an integer / use `mysql_real_escape_string` if it is a string.